# 2 Red LEGO compatible bricks

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I'm not sure where I got these 2 pieces from, and I'm wondering what are they, and which brand they belong to.

They are LEGO-compatible, but definitely not genuine LEGO.

There are no identifying marks.

Here are some photos:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those look like Best-lock bricks.

The red looks to be lighter and more-transparent, [like Best-lock bricks do compared to Lego](https://schou.dk/artikler/bestlock/).

[image]

The studs have [no markings](https://schou.dk/artikler/bestlock/).

[image]

The 1/2/5 looks like the ones found in Best-lock sets, like this one.

[image]

Comment: That's not it..

Comment: How do you know they aren't best-lock bricks?